# How to get a specific translation of drupal node with graphql

Tags: drupal, graphql, multilingual, gatsby

I am using `drupal 8` to build a headless page with `gatsby` and `graphql`.

**How to query a translation of a page?**

```
query MyQuery {
  allNodePage {
    nodes {
      body {
        value
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to get this `allNodePage.nodes.body.value` in a specific language.

Edit:
Here is the the graphiql allNodePage entity.

[image]

Edit_1:

According to [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi/issues/2794431) you can only query translations by modifying the api host-route (`/fr/jsonapi/node/page`) in `drupal 8`.

But in `gatsby-source-drupal`-plugin the api host route is not changeable in runtime.

Edit_2:

I try to translate a page node. Default language is english. I want to request the german translation which exists in drupal.

Comment: Does the lang code appear at any point in the page node?

Comment: I updated that question with a screenshot of the allPageNode entity. There is a langcode but its not possible to set the langcode.

Comment: I'm working on something similar, I will try get the node translation in the graphql query. How are you translating your node? Is it through the UI primary tabs menu? If you already found a solution please post it. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Rick. I switched to `strapi` to maintain data. As mentioned above you only can translate content with `/fr/jsonapi/node/page` oder `/en/jsonapi/node/page` in drupal. Another possibility is to add values for each language in your model. For example title__en, title__fr or content__en, content__fr.

Comment: Hi @Tomole. There is another way (incase you or anyone else is interested), I will post as an answer

Answer (score 3):

After some experimentation I see it's not working yet with Drupal JSON API, but I got it working with the Drupal GraphQL module. This can be used with Gatsby and gatsby-source-graphql instead of gatsby-source-drupal. The query would look something like this:

```
{
  nodeQuery(
    filter: {
      conditions:[
        {operator: IN, field: "type", value: ["my_node_type"]},
        {operator: EQUAL, field: "langcode", value: "de"},
      ]
    }
  ) {
    entities {
      ...on NodeMyNodeType {
        entityTranslation(language: DE) {
          entityLabel
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to filter `allNodePage` by `langcode` you can do it like this:

```
    query MyQuery {
      allNodePage(filter: {langcode: {eq: "fr_FR"}}) {
        nodes {
          body {
            value
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Of course, you can use a variable in place of "fr_FR" instead of hardcoding it

```
query MyQuery($lang: String!) {
      allNodePage(filter: {link: {eq: $lang:}}) {
        nodes {
          body {
            value
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: This seems like a awesome solution but `drupal` does not return the translation for french. Only if you change the api route in `gatsby` of `drupal` to http://localhost/fr/jsonapi. But I think you can not change the api route in runtime.

Comment: Are you able edit your question again with a little more detail about your problem. What exactly are you trying to achieve and what is blocking you from getting there? What is the default language, how many other languages are there?

Comment: Is there something under `relationships` of a node, that allows you to see the translated versions of the current page?

Comment: There is no translation in `relationships`. I updated the question.

Comment: I think you definitely need to find a way to create a relationship between translated pages, right? Otherwise, you need to make a separate build for each language.

Comment: OP asked for a graphql implementation. This answer uses JSONAPI.